# mysql subquery with more than one columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to do this

```
SELECT 
    `projects`.*,
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(`leads`.`id`),
        `pixel`.`uuid`,
        `pixel`.`project_id`
     FROM `leads` 
     LEFT JOIN `pixel` ON `leads`.`pixel` = `pixel`.`uuid`
     WHERE `projects`.`id` = `pixel`.`project_id`
     ) as leads

FROM `projects`
```

But I can't since my subquery select has more than one column, but I must have it so I can make the join, anyway around this? (all I need is the count)
thank you.

Comment: Why do you need those columns in the sub-query's select-list??? Just remove them!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `correlated Subquery` to `Inner Join` to show all the columns from your `subquery`

```
SELECT projects.*,
       a.*
FROM   projects P
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(leads.id) Cnt_id,
                          pixel.uuid,
                          pixel.project_id
                   FROM   leads
                          LEFT JOIN pixel
                                 ON leads.pixel = pixel.uuid) A
               ON projects.id = A.project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try to avoid the subquery:

```
SELECT
  projects.*,
  IFNUL(COUNT(leads.id).0) AS Cnt_id
FROM
  projects,
  LEFT JOIN pixel ON projects.id = pixel.project_id
  LEFT JOIN leads ON leads.pixel = pixel.uuid
GROUP BY
  projects.id
```

I suspect this will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
SELECT 
    `projects`.*,
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(`pixel`.`project_id`) 
    FROM `pixel` 
    WHERE `projects`.`id` = `pixel`.`project_id`) AS `num_pixels`,
    (SELECT COUNT(`leads`.`id`) FROM `leads`
                    LEFT JOIN `pixel` ON `leads`.`pixel` = `pixel`.`uuid`
                    WHERE `projects`.`id` = `pixel`.`project_id`) AS `num_leads`
FROM `projects`
```